# postgresql insert a structured data into jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-insert, jsonb

I use PostgreSQL 10.11 and would want to enter the following structure into a jsonb field:

```
{
 lead: {
    name: string,
    prep: boolean
 },
 secondary: {
   {
       name: string,
        prep: boolean
    },
    {
        name: string,
        prep: boolean
    }
}
```

so lead is an object with name and prep and secondary is an array of name and preps.
How can I do that? The scripts below is to create a table with jsonb field:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test01 (
  name JSONB DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL
) 
WITH (oids = false);

ALTER TABLE public.test01
  ALTER COLUMN id SET STATISTICS 0;

COMMENT ON COLUMN public.test01.name
IS '''[]''';


ALTER TABLE public.test01
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I'm trying this insert but get error:

```
INSERT INTO 
  public.test01
(
  name
  
)
VALUES 
('  
    {"lead": 
        "name": "Paint house", 
        "prep": "yes"}
     , 
     
    "Secondary":
        "name": "John", 
        "prep", "No"}
    }
');
```

It's the first time I'm using jsonb so a select example would also be helpful to know hoe to read the data as well.

Comment: You got three `}` yet only one `{`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed. Presumably, you meant:

```
INSERT INTO public.test01 (name)
VALUES (
'{
    "lead": { 
        "name": "Paint house", 
        "prep": "yes"
    }, 
    "Secondary": {
        "name": "John", 
        "prep": "No"
    }
}'::jsonb);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c20710ec0e63d28572eaea0ecc9eac92)**

Comment: the secondary part should be an array of name and preps. However, I get error when trying the above query.

Comment: @Msworkaholic: there was another problem in the JSON that I fixed too. I also added a DB Fiddle to my answer, for your reference.

Comment: Thank you It worked for an array with a little change too INSERT INTO public.test01 (name)
VALUES (
'{
    "lead": { 
        "name": "Paint house", 
        "prep": "yes"
    }, 
    "Secondary": [{
        "name": "John", 
        "prep": "No"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Joe", 
        "prep": "Y"
    }]
}'::jsonb);

Comment: Can you give an example of select as well?

Comment: @Msworkaholic: it is really about your JSON, not about the SQL itself. If you have a valid JSON string, you can just do: `select '{
    "lead": { 
        "name": "Paint house", 
        "prep": "yes"
    }, 
    "Secondary": {
        "name": "John", 
        "prep": "No"
    }
}'::jsonb myjson`